# Slider, after one click slider became works in an asynchronous way

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, slider

Hi I have problem with my slider please visit this site and check 
http://paruyr.bl.ee/ 
after click on my arrows it becomes work in an asynchronous way, ones it changes very fast and then slow and it repeats. I think it is from start slider() and stop slider(). set and clear interval

```
var sliderPrev = 0,
sliderNext = 1;   


$("#slider > img").fadeIn(1000); 
startSlider();

function startSlider(){

    count = $("#slider > img").size();
    loop = setInterval(function(){

        if (sliderNext>(count-1)) {
            sliderNext = 0;
            sliderPrev = 0;
        };

        $("#slider").animate({left:+(-sliderNext)*100+'%'},900);
        sliderPrev = sliderNext;
        sliderNext=sliderNext+1;

    },6000)
}

function prev () {
    var newSlide=sliderPrev-1;
    showSlide(newSlide);
}

function next () {
    var newSlide=sliderPrev+1;
    showSlide(sliderNext);
}

function stopLoop () {
    window.clearInterval(loop);
}

function showSlide(id) {
    stopLoop();
    if (id>(count-1)) {
            id = 0;
        } else if(id<0){
            id=count-1;
        }

        $("#slider").animate({left:+(-id)*100+'%'},900);
        sliderPrev = id;
        sliderNext=id+1;
        startSlider();

};

$("#slider, .arrows").hover(function() {
    stopLoop()
}, function() {
    startSlider()
});

function onlyNext () {
        var newSlide=sliderPrev+1;
        onlyShowSlide(newSlide);
}

function onlyShowSlide(id) {

    if (id>(count-1)) {
            id = 0;
        } else if(id<0){
            id=count-1;
        }

        $("#slider").animate({left:+(-id)*100+'%'},900);
        sliderPrev = id;
        sliderNext=id+1;        
};
```

Comment: If you can put this in a fiddle with dummy content it would help a lot since we cannot edit your site's js and test. I don't think your intervals are being cleared

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xv7bb/

Comment: I have already solved your issue in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting all stopLoop calls and put it in the starSlider function

```
function startSlider(){

    count = $("#slider > img").size();
    stopLoop();
    loop = setInterval(function(){

        if (sliderNext>(count-1)) {
            sliderNext = 0;
            sliderPrev = 0;
        };

        $("#slider").animate({left:+(-sliderNext)*100+'%'},900);
        sliderPrev = sliderNext;
        sliderNext=sliderNext+1;

    },6000)
}
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand why? i think it will not work

Comment: I am not 100% sure why it does not work, it seems that clearInterval is not clearing anything unless you put it before the setInterval. Itseems like a scope issue but I can't find anything on why this does not work

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that your code is at the end of body and not in head